# Change loading indicator Offset in Xamarin.Forms RefreshView

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

On Xamarin.Forms (iOS Android), I need to change the *loading-indicator* position on the RefreshView. I need to add offset, so the indicator is visible if you have a bar overlapping the ScrollView-RefreshView combo and trigger pullOnRefresh.

[Loading-indicator in the top edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODH6q.png)

EDIT: thanks to  [Junior Jiang - MSFT- Android solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62165720/5965343)

I also implement a solution for xamarin.iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RefreshView), typeof(CustomRefreshViewRenderer))] 
namespace CustomRefresh.iOS {
public class CustomRefreshViewRenderer : RefreshViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RefreshView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        foreach (var nativeView in Subviews)
            updateRefreshSettings(nativeView);

    }

    void updateRefreshSettings(UIView view) {
        if (view is UIScrollView)
        {
            var scrollView = view as UIScrollView;
            if (scrollView.RefreshControl != null)
            {
                var bounds = scrollView.RefreshControl.Bounds;
                scrollView.RefreshControl.Bounds = new CGRect(bounds.X, -(100), bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
            }
        }
        //add more scrollable view types
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi , could you share an image to explain the position you want to change to where place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom a **RefreshViewRenderer** to achieve that .

In **Android** , there is a `MOriginalOffsetTop` to modify the offset of loading indicator . In addition , also can use SetProgressViewOffset to set the start and end position of indicator .

Code as follow :

```
using Android.Content;
using RefreshViewDemo.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RefreshView), typeof(CustomRefreshViewRenderer))]
namespace RefreshViewDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomRefreshViewRenderer : RefreshViewRenderer
    {

        public CustomRefreshViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            MOriginalOffsetTop = 100;

           // SetProgressViewOffset(true, 100, 101);
        }

    }
}
```

In **iOS** , the loading indicator belong to `UIRefreshControl` of **UIScrollView** , there is no direct way to change it's offset . Unless override all content view in Renderer then can achieve that . You can refer this [Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/RefreshViewRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/RefreshViewRenderer.cs) to know what the `RefreshView` is made of .

====================Update=====================

Shared code is based on this official sample :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-refreshviewdemo/

For Android , just need to create a **CustomRefreshViewRenderer** class in android solution .

The effect of `SetProgressViewOffset(true, 100, 101)` , it seems like the indicator not moving :

[image]

Comment: I saw the renderer has available "SwipeLayout" property there. Should I changed from there or from the "this.SetProgressViewOffset".?

Comment: @JaekovSegovia What's the meaning of *from there or from the...* , my shared code is all in the renderer  . You can modify paramater to fit your want .

Comment: @JaekovSegovia I have updated the answer , you can have a look at that when have time .

Comment: Thanks for you anwer. It works as expected. I was using "SwipeRefreshLayout.SetProgressViewOffset(...)",  but you can call the method directly from the renderer.

Comment: @JaekovSegovia Yes , they are the same effect . https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylRNQ.png

Comment: You have to use a negative value for the start value in SetProgressViewOffset(true, -100, 200); and it will move